# Lost between PostgreSQL and ZF2 Service, Mapper, Hydrator, Models and their respective roles

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework2

I require your help because I'm a little lost about the data architecture.

For integrity and the possibility of being multi-platform, I delegates as much logic to PostgreSQL as possible. Thus I make a heavy use of views, materialized views, stored procedures, triggers, etc. On the other side, I went away from Doctrine (I never liked ORMs and it provides unecessary overhead to a fat database), as well as TableGateway since the flexibility to easily query procedures (as much as I understood from hours researching about it).

So : I am now getting myself lost when it comes about putting ZF2 together with PostgreSQL. Let's take a simple example : an article with a relations to multiple keywords :
 - I have models for both article and keywords ;
 - I have HydratorStrategy for both, which allows loading proper keyword array of objects into an article one with data fresh out of the DB ;
 - I have Fieldset for both too, allowing me to build forms and validate them in a flexible way ;

So far, it's ok... Then comes the Service and Mapper problematic. Let's imagine I want to create a new article. I get my "CreateForm", which provides the possibility to add 1 to n keywords.

Should I have a Service and a Mapper for both Article and Keyword models ?? Should I simply pass the POST array to the ArticleService which will call both necessary Mappers (Article and Keyword) ?? Would it be correct if the Service simply calls the ArticleMapper, which will itself calls the PgSQL "save_new_article()" function, e.g. passing values as a JSON object, and thus never calling any Keyword's Mapper ?? Wouldn't it be strange if I never make a direct use of KeywordMapper (I may not need to edit then, simply would create / delete them depending on articles' need).

Transferring most business logic to the DB with ZF2 seems not well documented. Also, I don't really know how am I supposed to seperate each and every roles. Should I simply get away with "each Model having its own Service and Mapper" to simply write down one Mapper that will serve as an SQL repository to my PgSQL views, functions and tables ?? Doing so, I would just need a "PgSQLService" class as well, isn't it ?? How about Hydrators then ??

Sorry for being not precise enough... But I am really confused right now, and wan't find any resource to better understand this type of cases.

Comment: There are a lot of question marks there. I think that is the reason your question doesn't receive any attention. You should make it less complex. Any way I think one of [my previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074019/zf2-creating-models-with-dependencies-in-mapper-without-servicemanager/36082093#36082093) will be of help here.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was affraid of and why I hesitated for some times before posting. The point is I may be a little too ambitious and going "off-road" without grasping everything well. Besides, everything I can find is "when using Doctrine", or "when using that", etc. Or when trying to stick with ServiceManager good practices, which not everyone does... It's quiete confusing sometimes !

You answers' gonna help me I think, will certainly reformulate my question(s) or mark it answered ! Thank you !